# python error : missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pyomo

I am really new(beginner) in Python and I am trying to implement an optimization problem using the pyomo library, in colab notebook.

The goal is to implement in pyomo the elastic net problem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

and then run it for λ=1 with a=1.

I have written the following implementation but then I get missing 1 required positional argument error when I am running it.

```
def elastic_net(alpha, lam, X, y):
    
    n, k = X.shape
    #Define the model
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel

    #Define sets for rows and column indices
    model.rowindices = pyo.Set(initialize=range(n))
    model.colindices = pyo.Set(initialize=range(k))

    #Declare decision variables
    model.beta=pyo.Var(model.colindices, domain=pyo.Reals)

    #Declare objective
    def obj_rule(model):
      return sum((sum (-X[i,j]*model.beta[j] for j in model.colindices)-y)**2 for i in model.rowindices)+alpha*(lam*(sum(model.beta[k] for k in model.colindices)+1/2*(1-lam)*sum(sum (model.beta[k] for k in model.colindices)**2)))
      #return sum((sum(A[i,j] * model.x[j] for j in model.colindices) - b[i])**2 for i in model.rowindices)
 
    model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense = pyo.minimize)

    #Declare constraints
    #no constraints for this problem
    return model
lasso_model = elastic_net(1, 1, X, y)
result = ipopt_solver.solve(lasso_model)
#pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(lasso_model).write()
print(f"the minimum value of the objective function is{lasso_model()}")
print(f"the value of β is{model.beta()}")

# objective, betas = ...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-31510e3ec601> in <module>
      1 lasso_model = elastic_net(1, 1, X, y)
----> 2 result = ipopt_solver.solve(lasso_model)
      3 #pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(lasso_model).write()
      4 print(f"the minimum value of the objective function is{lasso_model()}")
      5 print(f"the value of β is{model.beta()}")

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyomo/opt/base/convert.py in convert_problem(args, target_problem_type, valid_problem_types, has_capability, **kwds)
     58             raise ConverterError("Unknown suffix type: "+tmp)
     59     else:
---> 60         source_ptype = args[0].valid_problem_types()
     61 
     62     #

TypeError: valid_problem_types() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

> > please do not pay attention to the #comments some of them are just notes not part of my solution

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Whenever you see you are missing "self" it means there is a class and the method you are calling is a "regular" object's method (so not a class method, neither static...). So you need to invoke it for a specific object (e.g. for class A and some_method):
`a_instance = A()
a_instance.some_method()`
**And it means, that when defining that method "self" has to be the first parameter.**
Also some more context would help here....

Comment: You don't show the line that has the error, or where you create that object. Your code does not match your traceback

Comment: The error you just added in is not from the same code that you posted.  The code lines are different in the error report.  Please re-edit your question and paste the **exact same** code which produces the error you post.  You will get the best help in error fixing if you post the exact code + the error trace from that code.  I think I see your problem, but I'd like to confirm by seeing the code

Comment: The line `model = pyo.ConcreteModel` is suspicious. You probably want to create an object there of type `ConcreteModel`. It might need to be changed to  `model = pyo.ConcreteModel()`

Comment: hi i edited it again..i hope now is better

Answer (score 1):

The comment above is correct.  The source of your problems is that you used this:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel
```

instead of this:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
```

To explain what happens when you do this...  You have unwittingly created an "alias" for the function `ConcreteModel`, which is obviously not what you intended to do.  You wanted to *call* the function and get a model instance back.  If this concept is confusing, this below may help.  The punchline of the story is:  put parenthesis on that line to *call* the function.

```
In [14]: def make_model():
    ...:     return "I am a model object"
    ...: 

In [15]: m = make_model      # this is creating an "alias"

In [16]: print(m)
<function make_model at 0x1157c5e10>

In [17]: # because this "alias" refers to the function we can call it...

In [18]: m()
Out[18]: 'I am a model object'

In [19]: # we really wanted to assign m to the output of the function:

In [20]: m = make_model()

In [21]: print(m)
I am a model object
```